# Javascript audio recorder does not work inside android Webview

Tags: javascript, android, audio, webview

Javascript throws "Permission denied" when trying to record user audio input through android Webview application that loads https://addpipe.com/simple-recorderjs-demo/

Tried requesting and implementing sound/recording permissions like so

Manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.low_latency" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.audio.pro" />
    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.microphone"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

MyWebViewClient:

```
class MyWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {

    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    @Override
    public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
        Uri uri = Uri.parse(url);
        if (uri.getHost() != null && uri.getHost().contains("addpipe.com")) {
            return false;
        }

        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(url));
        view.getContext().startActivity(intent);
        return true;
    }
}
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS = 1;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO = 2;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE;
    private WebView mWebView;

    @SuppressLint("SetJavaScriptEnabled")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mWebView = findViewById(R.id.activity_main_webview);
        // Force links and redirects to open in the WebView instead of in a browser
        mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient());
        // Enable Javascript
        WebSettings webSettings = mWebView.getSettings();
        webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
        // REMOTE RESOURCE
         mWebView.loadUrl("https://addpipe.com/simple-recorderjs-demo/");
         mWebView.setWebChromeClient(new WebChromeClient());
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // No explanation needed; request the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS);
        }
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // No explanation needed; request the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO);
        } if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(MainActivity.this,
                Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
            // No explanation needed; request the permission
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(MainActivity.this,
                    new String[]{Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE},
                    MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, @NonNull String[] permissions, @NonNull int[] grantResults) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                } else {
                    System.out.println("FAILED MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS");
                }
                return;
            }case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                } else {
                    System.out.println("FAILED MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_RECORD_AUDIO");
                }
                return;
            }case MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE: {
                if (grantResults.length > 0
                        && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                } else {
                    System.out.println("FAILED MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_EXTERNAL_STORAGE");
                }
                return;
            }

        }
    }
```

I followed all the suggestions I could find about including and requesting the necessary permissions (RECORD_AUDIO, INTERNET, MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS, hardware.microphone, etc.

If I download the simple audio recorder and set it up as my own project (https://github.com/addpipe/simple-recorderjs-demo), then try to load it inside Webview, I get Javascript exception "Permission denied" upon clicking the Record button.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?